# Send audio and video stream from Raspberry Pi to localhost in Python using pyshine library

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I need to implement a code for streaming both audio and video from my Raspberry Pi 4 to localhost, but I have some problems. I managed to find the next code (which only sends the video stream to localhost:9000):

```
import cv2
import  pyshine as ps #  pip3 install pyshine==0.0.9
import pyaudio
HTML="""
<html>
<head>
<title>Monitoring camera and audio stream</title>
</head>

<body>
<img src="stream.mjpg" width='640' height='480' autoplay playsinline>
</body>
</html>
"""
def main():
    StreamProps = ps.StreamProps
    StreamProps.set_Page(StreamProps,HTML)
    address = ('myaddress',9000) # Enter your IP address
    try:
        StreamProps.set_Mode(StreamProps,'cv2')
        capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE,4)
        capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320)
        capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,240)
        capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS,30)
        StreamProps.set_Capture(StreamProps,capture)
        StreamProps.set_Quality(StreamProps,90)
        server = ps.Streamer(address,StreamProps)
        print('Server started at','http://'+address[0]+':'+str(address[1]))
        server.serve_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        capture.release()
        server.socket.close()

if _name=='main_':
    main()
```

My question is the following. How can I integrate in this code the audio stream? I searched for solutions but I couldn't find any that fits to my case.

Thank you for help and suggestions and have a nice day! :D

Comment: can you try using webrtc ? It can perform peer to peer video and audio streaming

Comment: unfortunately it's not a good solution for my application @SantoshBalaji